# Parallel upper triangle dataframe (matrix) with missing value in R

Tags: r, foreach, dataframe, doparallel

I have a vector `a` with missing value (the missing value is 5 and there might be more missing values).
I would like to create upper triangle dataframe (matrix) `s` in parallel.
The final dataframe `s` should be that is based upon `a` index on `b`:

```
> s
   1  2  3  4   6
1 22 32 42 52  82
2  0 42 52 62  92
3  0  0 62 72 102
4  0  0  0 82 112
6  0  0  0  0 142
```

I use the following code for it:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

    b<-c(11,21,31,41,61)
    a<-c(1,2,3,4,6)
    N<-length (a)
    cl<-makeCluster(4)
    registerDoParallel(cl)

    #loop
    #result is a list of vectors
    s <- foreach(i=a) %:%
      foreach(j=i:N, .combine='c') %dopar% {
        as.numeric(b[i]+b[j])  } 


    stopCluster(cl)

    s <- t(vapply(s, function(x) {
      x <- rev(x)
      length(x) <- N
      rev(x)
    }, FUN.VALUE = numeric(N)))

    s[lower.tri(s)] <- 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

       b<-c(11,21,31,41,61,71)
        a<-c(1,2,3,4,6)
        N<-length (a)
        cl<-makeCluster(4)
        registerDoParallel(cl)

        #loop
        #result is a list of vectors
        s <- foreach(i=a) %:%
          foreach(j=a[i:N], .combine='c') %dopar% {
            as.numeric(b[i]+b[j])  } 


        stopCluster(cl)

        s <- t(vapply(s, function(x) {
          x <- rev(x)
          length(x) <- N
          rev(x)
        }, FUN.VALUE = numeric(N)))

        s[lower.tri(s)] <- 0
    s<-as.data.frame(s)
    colnames(s)<-a
    rownames (s)<-a

    > s
       1  2  3  4   6
    1 22 32 42 52  82
    2  0 42 52 62  92
    3  0  0 62 72 102
    4  0  0  0 82 112
    6  0  0  0  0 142
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach using the `outer` function.

```
x <- 1:6
a <- outer(x, x, "+")
b <- a[-5, -5]
b[lower.tri(b)] <- 0
b
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    2    3    4    5    7
# [2,]    0    4    5    6    8
# [3,]    0    0    6    7    9
# [4,]    0    0    0    8   10
# [5,]    0    0    0    0   12
```

**UPDATE:**

If you don't want to build the whole matrix in advance, remove the missing value from the vector `x` in advance will do that.

```
x <- c(1:4, 6)
a <- outer(x, x, "+")
a[lower.tri(a)] <- 0
a
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    2    3    4    5    7
# [2,]    0    4    5    6    8
# [3,]    0    0    6    7    9
# [4,]    0    0    0    8   10
# [5,]    0    0    0    0   12
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to build the whole matrix in advance due to code complexity inside the loops. I want to create it as shown in the example with no added lines and columns. The lines are OK in my example code only something to change in the rows.

Comment: Thanks again. It looks much better, but I need to do it in parallel (using foreach) and in addition, instead of the '+' there is a complex code that depends on i and j the loop values. Please refer to my attached example. (In addition, I use 'a' as vector and you use it as x)